# Prove an ODE has asymptotically stable equilibrium point.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

I am given the ODE
$$\dot{x}=-f(x)$$
( $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$ with $x$ being a function of $t$)

with
$$f(0)=0$$
$x \in \mathbb{R}$

such that $f$ is locally Lipschitz on $(-a,a)$, $a >0$

and $xf(x) >0$ for all $x \in (-a,a)- \{0\}$

Prove that $0$ is an asymptotically stable equilibrium point of the ODE.

I tried the following
$$\dot{x} x =-  f(x)x $$
$$\frac{x^2}{2} = -\int_0^x f(y)ydy$$
and take $$V(x)=\frac{x^2}{2} + \int_0^x f(y)ydy$$ as a Lyapunov function. Now $f(x)x >0$ so $V(x) >0$
Also it's clear that $V(0)=0$ be
So $V(x)$ is positive defined.

And this is where I am stuck, for 0 to asymptotically stable then $V^*(x) := \frac{dV}{dt}$ must be negative defined, but I can't see why this is.
How can I prove this?

Comment: $\dot x$ refers in general to $\frac{dx}{dt}$, there seems to be no $t$ in your problem, can you clarify ?

Comment: Yes, it's $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$. $x$ is a function of $t$.

Answer (score 1):

The Lyapunov function is $V(x)=x^2/2$. Its derivative
$$
\dot V= x\dot x= -xf(x)
$$
is negative definite.